# Validate form using validate.properties file in SpringBoot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I am trying to validate form in Spring Boot,that when i click on submit button,jsp will show me messages how to fill fields(or not).I created validation.properties which i have messages,but I always get error `"No message found under code for locale 'en_US'"` ? 
Does someone know how could i show these messages in jsp?My validation.properties file is located in `src/main/resources/static` folder,and in my jsp file i put link for validation.properties file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/validation.properties"></link>`.
In validation class I have:

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    UserRegistration userRegistrated = (UserRegistration) target;

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "ime", "NotEmpty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "prezime", "NotEmpty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "NotEmpty");

    if (service.findUsers(userRegistrated.getEmail())) {
        errors.rejectValue("email", "ExistUser");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "NotEmpty");
    if (userRegistrated.getPassword().length() < 4) {
        errors.rejectValue("password", "LengthPass");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "repeatPassword", "NotEmpty");
    if (!userRegistrated.getRepeatPassword().equals(userRegistrated.getPassword())) {
        errors.rejectValue("repeatPassword", "MatchPass");
    }
}
```

where `ime`,`prezime`,`email`,`password`,`repeatPassword` are corresponding to fields in bean `UserRegistration`:

```
class UserRegistration {
    private String ime;
    private String prezime;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String repeatPassword;

    public UserRegistration() {
    }

    public String getIme() {
        return ime;
    }

    public void setIme(String ime) {
        this.ime = ime;
    }

    public String getPrezime() {
        return prezime;
    }

    public void setPrezime(String prezime) {
        this.prezime = prezime;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRepeatPassword() {
        return repeatPassword;
    }

    public void setRepeatPassword(String repeatPassword) {
        this.repeatPassword = repeatPassword;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserRegistration [ime=" + ime + ", prezime=" + prezime + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password
                + ", repeatPassword=" + repeatPassword + "]";
    }
}
```

and my form in jsp looks like:

```
<form:form id="register" action="${action}" method="post" modelAttribute="userRegistration">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="ime">Ime:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="ime" type="text" placeholder="Ime" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="ime" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="prezime">Prezime:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="prezime" type="text" placeholder="Prezime"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="prezime" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">Korisnicko ime(e-mail):</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="password">Lozinka:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="password" type="password" placeholder="Lozinka"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="repeatPassword">Potvrda lozinke:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="repeatPassword" type="password" placeholder="Potvrda lozinke"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="repeatPassword" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

My validation.properties file:

```
NotEmpty.UserRegistration.ime=Polje je obavezno!
NotEmpty.UserRegistration.prezime=Polje je obavezno!
NotEmpty.UserRegistration.email=Polje je obavezno!
NotEmpty.UserRegistration.password=Polje je obavezno!
NotEmpty.UserRegistration.repeatPassword=Polje je obavezno!
ExistUser.UserRegistration.email=Korisnik sa takvim e-mailom vec postoji u bazi!
LengthPass.UserRegistration.password=Lozinka treba da je duza od 4 karaktera!
MatchPass.UserRegistration.repeatPassword=Lozinke se ne poklapaju!
```

I have tried to put validation.properties in `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` folders,but i got the same result.I think that problem is how to access that validation.properties file,but i don't know how to do it?Do I need to write some configuration for it?I searched the internet and there are explanation mostly for spring(not for spring boot),i don't know if it's the same..Thanks in advance!

Comment: solved it,i just added `spring.messages.basename=validation` in application.properties and moved validation.properties to src/main/resources.